# Video do not pause in Expo video When back button is pressed

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Android back button doesnt stop the video (Expo video player)  , when it is pressed. I want to pause the video in android device when the back button is pressed in order to exit from full screen.

Please let me know what can I do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply a lot of docs about ExoPlayer in internet and its official docs in github,
but for pausing your Exoplayer sample you need override onBackPressed() method and pause exo object:

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    player.setPlayWhenReady(false);// for pausing- set true for resuming
}
```

Comment: where does this go ?

Comment: in your activity that handle Exoplayer! for example you have exoplayer in MainActivty.java so you should add this method in MainActivity.java

Comment: It doesnt work , i tired that. And i have been talking about expo player, not exoplayer,  so i think that might the confusion here.